# automate chrome extension installation when user access my website

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i need my chrome extension to be downloaded and installed automatically, when user access my website from Google chrome. 
my extension is stored in my web-server, should i need to store the extension in google web store for the above purpose.
**is it possible to provide a shortcut to my extension in desktop also.**

i am able to manually install the extension, but need to installed automatically using java-script or any other method

i have found some similar post using registry editing etc, but this will not meet my requirement.

Comment: You realize that being able to do so would be really, really worrying security-wise?

Comment: If you can accept hosting in the Web Store, the closest thing available is [inline installation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Security restrictions](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128748#c27) prevent an extension from being installed from a web site other than the Chrome Web Store.  **You cannot bypass this restriction** without control of the end-user machine.

The Web Store does not provide any mechanism for automatic extension installation.  (This is a very good thing.)

On a standard Chrome installation, the only way to install an extension outside of the Web Store is by dragging a crx file onto the Extensions preferences page (chrome://extensions).

If you have administrative control of the target computers that the extension is to be instaled on, you can write a script that [installs the extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html).

Comment: i think inline installation will be ok for my need . https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation